# How does C++ handle template functions with respect to type conversions

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction

My general idea of how some compilers work, is that during the type checking phase (semantic analysis) the AST is annotated with type conversion information, so with a example such as: `1 + 1.2`, the node representing `1` will be annotated with a float (or double) to indicate that it has to be converted so that it can match the function call `operator+(float, float)` (or `float.operator+(float)`).

However, when it comes to templated functions arguments such as:

```
template<typename T, typename B>
void test(T a, B b) {
    a + b;
}
...
test(23, 12);
test(23, 1.2);
test(2.3, 12);
test(2.3, 1.2);
```

A great combination of different types can be passed to this function. Therefore, how is type conversion annotations of the AST `a` and `b` handled? Is the function duplicated for the possible different types it's called with? Is the function inlined?

Comment: I get your point, but `float` is not the best example as it's an intrinsic type. I.e., there is no `float.operator+(float)`.

Comment: consider that `test` is not a function. It is just a template. Only when you instantiate it, eg `test<int,double>` then thats a function more or less like any other function

Comment: what is `B` btw? typo and it should be `void test(T a, B b) {` ?

Comment: [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=dGVtcGxhdGUgPHR5cGVuYW1lIFQsIHR5cGVuYW1lIFQyPgp2b2lkIHRlc3QoVCBhLCBUMiBiKSB7CiAgICBhICsgYjsKfQoKaW50IG1haW4oKQp7CiAgdGVzdCgyMywgMTIpOwogIHRlc3QoMjMsIDEuMik7CiAgdGVzdCgyLjMsIDEyKTsKICB0ZXN0KDIuMywgMS4yKTsKfQo=&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the function duplicated for the possible different types it's called with?

Yes. Thats roughly the idea of writing templates. `test` is not a function, `test<int,double>` is.

The following is not really what happens but it works as a mental model to quite some extend.

You call

```
test(1,1.0);
```

Compiler deduces `T` and `B` to be `int` and `double`, respectively. Hence it will instantiate something along the line of:

```
void test(int a, double b) {
    a + b;
}
```

Only now the compiler is required and has all the information needed to see if `a+b` requires to promote one of the operands. The usual rules do apply: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I declared a static int in the templated function and incremented it.  It returned 1 for ever unique call to the templated function and 2 when I entered the same types twice.